# Do I use was or were?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wanted to say "I think the primary use case for USB A were thumbdrives" but I am utterly unsure whether it's "was" because *the* primary use case or it's "were" because thumbdrive**s**.

Comment: The subject and verb should match for number. The subject is the singular NP "the primary use case for USB A", thus singular "was" is correct.

Comment: What @BillJ said. In contexts where a singular subject is being "equated" with a plural noun phrase, or vice-versa, the actual verb form agrees with the syntactic subject, whichever way round it goes. So *The primary use case for USB A **was** thumbdrives*, OR *Thumbdrives **were** the primary use case for USB A.*

Comment: Grammar aside, don't say this. It's factually incorrect. USB A predates thumb drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I think the primary use case for USB A **was** thumb drives."

"Use case" is the subject of the verb, and it's singular, so "was" is correct.